# is it possible in scala/Akka to read the .xls file and .xlsx as a chunk?

Tags: scala

Upload a file in chunk to a server including additional fields

```
 def readFile(): Seq[ExcelFile] = {
    logger.info(" readSales method initiated: ")
    val source_test = source("E:/dd.xlsx")
    println( "  source_test "+source_test)
   val source_test2 = Source.fromFile(source_test)
    println( "  source_test2 "+source_test)
    //logger.info(" source: "+source)
    for {
      line <- source_test2.getLines().drop(1).toVector
      values = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
     // logger.info(" values are the: "+values)
    } yield ExcelFile(Option(values(0)), Option(values(1)), Option(values(2)), Option(values(3)))
  }

  def source(filePath: String): String = {
    implicit val codec = Codec("UTF-8")
    codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    codec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    Source.fromFile(filePath).mkString
  }
```

upload route,

```
path("upload"){
  (post & extractRequestContext) { ctx => {
    implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
    implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
    fileUpload("fileUploads") {
      case (fileInfo, fileStream) =>
        val path = "E:\\"
        val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(path).resolve(fileInfo.fileName))
        val wResult = fileStream.runWith(sink)
        onSuccess(wResult) { rep => rep.status match {
          case Success(_) => 
            var ePath = path + File.separator + fileInfo.fileName 
            readFile(ePath)
            _success message_
          case Failure(e) => _faillure message_
        } }
    }
  } }
}
```

am using above code, is it possible in scala or Akka can I read the excel file like chunk file

Comment: what do you mean by - `is it possible in scala or Akka can I read the excel file like chunk file`? Also, I don't see anything related to `akka` or `play framework` in this question so removed those tags.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I have an excel file with 3GB  if I upload the same file in one user in my server no issue's raised when more than 2 users hit the service am getting heap size issue, for that am thinking by using yield keyword or chunk file type uploading. is there any better way can I upload my file without getting heap size issue. I have already set the heap size, 'javaOptions in run ++= Seq(  "-XX:+UseNUMA", "-XX:-UseBiasedLocking","-Xms256M", "-Xmx400M", "-Xss1M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=128m", "-XX:+UseParallelGC", "-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100","-XX:GCTimeRatio=19")'

Comment: The thing is that here you are processing the file. The issue is not with uploading.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code, it like you are having an issue with the post-processing (after upload) of the file.

If uploading a 3GB file is working even for 1 user then I assume that it is already `chunked` or `multipart`.

The first problem is here - `source_test2.getLines().drop(1).toVector` which create a Vector ( > 3GB ) with all line in file.

The other problem is that you are keeping the whole `Seq[ExcelFile]` in memory which should be bigger than `3 GB` (because of Java object overhead).

So whenever you are calling this `readFile` function, you are using more than `6 GB` memory.

You should try to avoid creating such large object in your application and use things like `Iterator` instead of `Seq`

```
def readFile(): Iterator[ExcelFile] = {
  val lineIterator = Source.fromFile("your_file_path").getLines
  lineIterator.drop(1).map(line => {
    val values = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    ExcelFile(
        Option(values(0)),
        Option(values(1)),
        Option(values(2)),
        Option(values(3))
    )
  })
}
```

The advantage with Iterator is that it will not load all the things in memory at once. And you can keep using Iterators for further steps.

Comment: `thank you` the above code works only for .csv files am exactly getting the issue in this line `val lineIterator = Source.fromFile("E:\test.xlsx").getLines` 
**[default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] Error during processing of request: 'Input length = 1'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
background log: info: java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1**

Comment: is there any default method for uploading the excel file chunk by chunk in Akka

Comment: akka-http or PlayFramework ? Also the error which you provided is being raised because of some other piece of code which is not provided in your question, so I can not help with that.

Comment: am using **akka-http**  `path("upload"){
(post & extractRequestContext) {
ctx => {
implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
fileUpload("fileUploads") {
case (fileInfo, fileStream) =>
val path = "E:\\"
val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(path) resolve fileInfo.fileName)
al wResult = fileStream.runWith(sink)
onSuccess(wResult) { rep =>
rep.status match {
case Success(_) =>
var ePath = path + File.separator + fileInfo.fileName
readFile(ePath)
_success message_
case Failure(e) =>
_faillure message_
}
}
}
}
}
}
`

Comment: You are already using `fileUpload` directive of `akka-http` which streams the upload file from a multi-part request and that stream is then running through a sink to be stored on disk. Your upload should be working just fine and should suffice for your purpose unless you explicitly need `chunked` upload which can be tricky to implement. Like I mentioned eariler, your problem was not with upload but the post-processing which you were doing int your `readFile` function. If you avoid loading the whole file by using `Iterator` further down the line, you will not face the OutOfMemory issue.